# Create a .pcd point cloud file from multiple image files

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I want to create a 3D PCD file and then display it. I'm not able to figure out how to create a PCD file for a real life object.

Comment: In order to get answered, specify your queston and problem more deeply. What do you mean by point cloud from image files? What do you mean by create a PCD file? What do you mean by "for a real life object"?

Comment: read and try to replicate the tutorials from the pcl website. pointcloud.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "real life object" but the PCD file format is quite well documented:

[Information about the file format](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php)

You can visualize it using the [Visualizer](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html) class ([tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php)).

So e.g. make a scan of your "real world object", store point data in a PCD file and visualize it.

PS: Hm, what was your question?